# JavaFX wait for render

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a simple problem that I'am unable to resolve. If I run this example at the time of printing "AFTER" Scene is not rendered, only empty Stage. If I do runLater the sequence is in order - scene is rendered before "AFTER LATER". How can I wait in code for render (Quantum Toolkit) to complete?

```
public final void start(final Stage primaryStage)
{
            Button btn = new Button("Hello World!");

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(btn);

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
            primaryStage.show();

            // TODO - wait for render?

            System.out.println("AFTER");

            Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println("AFTER LATER"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: [primaryStage.setOnShown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnShown-javafx.event.EventHandler-)?

Comment: Nope, setOnShown is the fastest of them all. No Scene with buttons, just Stage. ,I've added a picture.

Comment: Ok, then try `btn.sceneProperty().addListener()`.

Comment: How are you able to tell the scene is not fully rendered? On my machine the lines are printed and the window is displayed—with the scene's content—at virtually the same time. I'd actually say each line is printed _after_ the window is rendered. The lines are in order as well: "ON SHOWN" -> "AFTER" -> "AFTER LATER".

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you need to wait for the rendering to finish?

Comment: I tried to show the view then do some work on fx thread (synchronously). I guess it's not working like that, I have to do the work (as simple it is) in new thread.

Comment: If that work is expensive, and you run it on the FX thread, then it will freeze your UI. Always run blocking or expensive work on a background thread.